# How to get MathJax/ASCIIMath to ignore certain words

Tags: javascript, mathjax, asciimath

I know MathJax, especially with ASCIIMath, processes a lot of different words into symbols. But is there any way to prevent it from converting specific words?

For example, it turns every instance of `lt` into `<`. Can I make it so that it keeps it as `lt` instead?

Comment: Is `l t` (with a space) enough for you? AFAIK, there's no escape character in asciimathml.

Comment: Sadly, no, because the user will be the one inputting the equations.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand the question then, I'm afraid.

Comment: cant you use the delimiter? put lt outside of it ?!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is a correct way to do it, but I was able to get it to render as `lt` by putting a `\` between the `l` and `t` like this: `l\t`.

Comment: That worked for me in a draw.io mathematical typesetting

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is very old. But I stumbled across the same problem while adding a math formula to an AsciiDoc text.

```
\frac{5\ \text{GT }}{\text{s}} \times \frac{1\ \text{Bit}}{\text{T} \times \text{Lane}} \times \frac{\text{8 Bit}}{\text{10 Bit}} \times 16\ \text{Lanes} = \frac{64\ \text{GBit}}{\text{s}} =  \frac{8\ \text{GByte}}{\text{s}}
```

I just added white-space after the `GT` to avoid rendering it to `>`.

Answer (score 1):

Double-quoted (`"`) string works for me, see an example below:

```html
<script>
MathJax = {
  loader: {
    load: ['input/asciimath', 'output/chtml', 'ui/menu']
  },
};
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/startup.js"></script>

<p>Without quotes: `c_in = c_out ^ gamma`</p>

<p>With quotes: `c_"in" = c_"out" ^ gamma`</p>
```

Comment: Ran into this with things like `C^(combined)`. Yes, double quotes "work" (i.e., `C^("combined")`, but they change the rendering of the superscript from italics to regular, which ruins the visual, it's especially noticeable with `C^(comb"in"ed)`